# Next.js: How to access geolocation information provided by middleware.js?

Tags: next.js, geolocation

The Next.JS middleware feature allows for easy adding of geolocation based information to a request:

```
// /middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req) {
    const { nextUrl: url, geo } = req
    const country = geo.country || 'DE'
    url.searchParams.set('country', country)
    return NextResponse.rewrite(url)
}
```

How do I access this information from the code of a page? I am sure there is an easy way, and I was just not able to find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a straight-forward solution.

Make sure /pages/_app.js has the following lines in it (default if created with npx create-next-app):

```
// /pages/_app.js

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Then the country (or other information added by the NextJS middleware can be accessed directly like this:

```
let geoCountry = pageProps.country;
```

Comment: I don't believe this works - do you have a real example or documentation reference?

Comment: It works when your provider, like Vercel or AWS, adds it to the headers.  

Wont work on its own.  
    
There is also a line in documentation explaining geo headers.  
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-server#nextrequest

Comment: Thanks, @Wespen, for adding this. Indeed it only works if using a provider that adds the header. We have it in production with Vercel.